# Import of product via CSV (need to update, not replace, not append)

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, importexport

I'm having this situation where I need to import around 300 products with different attributes and 4-8 pictures for every products. I have created a valid csv file, within my ERP program (accounting software, which use MSSQL as database). As I said csv file which is created from my locale software is 100% valid and the importation is working just fine. All the attributes and pictures are in it's place.

Now i encountered to another problem, which I don't know how to solve. I have used the function "Replace Existing Complex Data" when import, but this function deletes all the existing data (products which I manually added to for example "Featured" or "Our suggestion" category).

So I tried to fix this with the "Append Complex Data", but this function is not working for me because it duplicates the pictures (append the pictures).

The best scenario would be if it is there a function just to update the complex data, not to replace, not to append.

UPDATED

Could this be done, by setting up that the Magento doesn't apply the import changes for the specific category?

Comment: If you don't need to change images, then delete it from csv. I think it will always duplicate those images because you have different name for them.

Comment: The name for the images are the same. Always. No change

Comment: anabody? that have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the "append" mode, but exclude everything from your CSV file which is already in the shop, i.e. the images. Only include the data you want to update and the SKU.